# How to make so that I can consistently get around a list of sites with a single scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I wrote code for launching scrapy spider from Python script.Now,I want bypass list of websites consistently,i.e. I run spider for one website and when it finished scraping,I close spider and call repeatedly it for another website.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from datetime import datetime
start_urls=['https://sentek.ru/','http://www.s-kab.ru/',https://sevkab.nt-rt.ru/',http://www.mikroprovod.ru/']

for start_url in start_urls:
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    domain = start_url.split('//')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1]
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    current_time = current_time.replace("-", ".")
    process.crawl('procurement', start_url=start_url,domain=domain,time=current_time)
    process.start()
```

But error 
       `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`  appears when I start scraping the second site.I know   it is happens due to features of TwistedReactor that it cannot be restarted.I will want to get know,is there some way to running the reactor once and always re-create spider in it?
Thanks for attention!:)

UPDATE!Solution
I decided to create separate process for each spider,for this I used multiprocessing library.This helps to avoid mistakes `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable` and performs sequential scraping websites.Here's the code:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process

def create_spider(start_url):
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    domain = start_url.split('//')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1]
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    current_time = current_time.replace("-", ".")
    process.crawl('procurement', start_url=start_url, domain=domain, 
    time=current_time)
    process.start()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_urls = [
                  'http://www.samaracable.ru/',
              'http://www.skz67.ru/', 'http://www.uralcable.ru/',
              'http://www.ufimcabel.ru/', 'http://www.chuvashcable.ru/', 
              'https://uncomtech.ru/']
   for start_url in start_urls:
       proc = Process(target=create_spider, args=(start_url,))
       proc.start()
       proc.join()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very close to working, you just missed an important detail. `CrawlProcess` is actually designed to run *multiple* spiders at the same time!

> CrawlProcess
>   A class to run multiple scrapy crawlers in a process simultaneously.

So to fix that all you need to do is move your `CrawlProcess` object creation and starting of it outside of your loop:

```
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
^^^
for start_url in start_urls:
    domain = start_url.split('//')[-1].split('/')[0].split('www.')[-1]
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    current_time = current_time.replace("-", ".")
    process.crawl('procurement', start_url=start_url,domain=domain,time=current_time)
process.start()
^^^
```

Comment: Just adding the link to the relevant part of the documentation - https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question!I tried this way,before I had asked this question,but for some reason it greatly slows down work of program,especially if the number of sites is large ,maybe because spiders is created for each site and they work almost simultaneously(always switches between sites),it is badly slow down.Maybe there is some solution that will allow the spider to completely scraping the website and only then move on to the next one

Comment: @IvanNadin That's definitely the case. All of these crawl processes have to share a single crawling process while crawling simultaniously - if you have a lot of crawlers there might not be enough resources to go around and some will have to wait for their turn. There are few ways you can deal with this: you can either schedule them as a chain of batches, i.e. crawl 5 spiders once they finish crawl the next 5 and so on or start multiple python processes or threads with 5 spiders each. The later approach can be as easy as simply calling crawler script multiple times with different start urls.

Comment: To add to that you can continue to optimize a single process to handle more crawlers. Increasing [REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=reactor%20twisted#reactor-threadpool-maxsize) setting to something higher than default 10 could help.